# What does lowercaseStringWithLocale do?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, localization, nsstring

Does anyone know exactly what the new (iOS 6) lowercaseStringWithLocale method of NSString does? The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) is very skimpy, and I didn't find a single reference to this method in Apple's developer forums.

While localizing my app, I'm interested in changing words from my strings file to lowercase when they appear in a sentence -- except in the German version, where some words should stay in uppercase at all times. Is that what this method is for? Or something completely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discussion in [`lowercaseString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) might shed some light:

> **Note:** This method performs the canonical (non-localized) mapping. It is suitable for programming operations that require stable results not depending on the user's locale preference. For localized case mapping for strings presented to users, use the corresponding `lowercaseStringWithLocale:` method.

So if you're computing the lowercase version of a string for a purpose such as case-insensitive database lookup, use `lowercaseString`. If you intend to show the user the result, then use `lowercaseStringWithLocale`.

Note that `lowercaseStringWithLocale` won't make a decision based on the actual words as to whether the word should be lowercased or not. It does what you ask it to do, and doesn't question your motives.

Comment: Okay, so I can't use it for my German! But I'm curious to understand this. Could you give an example of a word that would be treated differently by these two methods, to illustrate why the WithLocale version is needed?

Comment: Perhaps "STRASSE" would be converted to "straße" when used with a German locale. I don't know for sure and I'm not in a position to try it at the moment.

Comment: I've added an answer with an actual example... The infamous Turkish i.

Comment: I was hoping for an example that showed the result of both methods on a particular word and why one result is preferable to the other in different situations. But as a general rule I think this answers my question: "If you're computing the lowercase version of a string for a purpose such as case-insensitive database lookup, use lowercaseString. If you intend to show the user the result, then use lowercaseStringWithLocale."

Answer (score 0):

Lower/uppercasing is indeed locale-dependent. The only example I know about (and it's a killer one, a source of many globalization bugs) is the Turkish i issue. See here for an overview: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/whats-wrong-with-turkey.html

Basically, when you uppercase "Hi" you get "HI" except for Turkey where you get "Hİ"

Likewise, when you lowercase "HI" you get "hi" except for Turkey where you get "hı"